# TabBar image size in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbaritem, landscape-portrait

I am working on application which supports both **Portrait and Landscape** mode. I am using default TabBarController in Storyboard.

```
NOTE: I am adding custom offset on images
```

> In Portrait mode the image size of tabbarItems are looking well nice.
>   But when i am rotating my device to landscape mode, the TabbarItems
>   images are looking too small

How can I resolve this so that i can have the bigger size for landscape mode.

Here are the screenshots for both portrait and landscape mode.

[image: Portrait]
[image: Landscape]

Any better approach for tab bar in landscape mode ?

Thanks!

**#Edit 1**
I added custom offset for landscape mode (all are having a negative value) and the size increased. but on tapping the size is increasing (on each tap)

**#Edit 2**
I removed left and right inset from landscape mode and the increasing image size is fixed but the size is again decreased.

Any Suggestion about what's happening ?

Comment: Are you giving custom offset to the images?

Comment: It'd be better if you cropped those images so that we only see the important parts.

Comment: @RikeshSubedi, Yes, I am giving custom offset to images for keeping them in center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ran into this, you need to set the tabbarItem's landscapeImagePhoneInsets property as well.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to add imageInsets

```
 var item0: UITabBarItem? = tabBarController.tabBar.items[0]
 item0?.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(3, 0, -3, 0)
```

Comment: i am doing same from storyboard

Answer (score 0):

If you have set icons from storyboard try setting same image for landscape also.[See the landscape property and set image like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyYDq.png)